# python tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient max_clients doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, tornado

we are using python tornado server for a new project.
the server should work like a node.js server, accepting thousands of connections and keeping them open for a long time until a response is ready.

the response is a result of a multiple http access to external resources, so of course we need to support concurrently a lot of http client connections open simultaneously as well (a few hundreds at least).

we tried to configure the AsyncHTTPClient like that:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient.configure("tornado.simple_httpclient.SimpleAsyncHTTPClient", max_clients=1000, defaults=dict(connect_timeout=float(10), request_timeout=float(100)))

tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

it seems that our server is working fine but we have a problem with the httpclient - it doesn't seem to scale to more than a dozen connections and the application simply hangs until it gets a lot of timeout error (error 599).

1. any idea if the tornado async http client is buggy or do we use it in a wrong manner?
2. any ideas on a replacement technology? (python?)

Comment: This use of `AsyncHTTPClient.configure` looks correct to me. Are you sure that the timeouts are coming from the `max_clients` limit and not the external site(s) you're connecting to? If it's a third-party API, they may have their own limits on concurrent requests. Also make sure that you're not constructing any global `AsyncHTTPClient` instances before this code runs.

Comment: i suspect the timeouts come from the external site. i tried with a different one and it seems ok